# Most Efficient Many-To-Many Linq Query

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, many-to-many

I have the following setup:

Table: Question

- QuestionId

Table: QuestionTag

- QuestionId
- TagId

Table: Tag

- TagId
- TagName

A question can have many tags and a tag can have many questions (many-to-many)

I'm using LingToSql. I'm trying to create a method-based query that will allow me to pass in a list of tag names and return all questions with those tags. I just can't seam to wrap my head around how to do this.

Would someone be kind enough to show me an example of how to do this using a method-based Linq query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<string> tagNames = ...;
var questions = db.Questions.Where(
     q => q.QuestionTags.Any(
          qt => tagNames.Contains(qt.Name)));
```

The hard thing about understanding this is the deep nesting of operators. After a while it becomes natural.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm. Funny, it is so obvious after I see it.